# disabel for custom post Auto Upload Images

Tags: custom-post-types

hi can i disable this plugin for custom post type thanks

https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-upload-images/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general idea. You could put this in your theme's functions.php. Obviously you may need to adapt the items in parentheses, especially the first one:

```
remove_post_type_support( 'your_custom_post_type', 'auto-upload-images' );
```

Comment: thanks for respons but not working and steal upload custom post type image